# Quadratic equation formula for a,b,c from 3 points

Tags: algorithms, quadratics, quadratic-programming

I can solve for a, b, c given three points for a parabola for example (1,1)(2,4)(3,9) but i need to create a program which returns a,b,c in the form:

$$y = ax^2 + bx + c$$

What is a formula that will find out a, b, c? Someone on another forum mentioned Lagrange but being a high school student i don't know much about Uni level physics. Also i can work with matrices if anyone has a matrix formula - but please explain your formulas as to why it works!

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
Itechmatrix

Comment: See:-https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/quadratic-equation-from-3-points.404174/

Comment: @Mick I can't find a working formula on those pages?

Comment: Look for Xitami’s reply. The post also provides a link explaining how to find the inverse of a matrix. Also, @JoeTaxpayer has also included a method (namely Cramer’s rule) to find the solution of that matrix.

Answer (score 0):

When you plug in the three points, you have three equations in three unknowns, where the unknowns are A,B,and C. Use matrix arithmetic to solve via simple program.

By Matrix, I mean using [Cramer's rule](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/system-of-equations-solver/system-3x3.php).

[image]

Comment: Matrix Arithmetic? Could you please elaborate on that @JoeTaxpayer?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: To make things a bit easier, I think the roles of a and x (also b vs y and c vs z) should be interchanged instead. This is because the values of a, b, c are the required.

Comment: @Mick - When working with my students I make an effort to help them not get hooked on the variable designations. I was clear in the answer I posted that OP need to be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ($x_1, y_1$), ($x_2, y_2$) and ($x_3, y_3$) are three points that satisfy the equation:

$y= ax^2 + bx +c$

we get the three equations:

$y_1= ax_1^2 + bx_1 +c$

$y_2= ax_2^2 + bx_2 +c$

$y_3= ax_3^2 + bx_3 +c$

now $a, b, c$ are the unknowns and we have three equations in three variables. Now you could use Cramer's rule as suggested in the other answer.

In Matrix from:

$
   Y =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   y_1  \\
   y_2 \\
   y_3
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
   X=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
   x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
   x_3^2 & x_3 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

and

$
   A =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   a  \\
   b \\
   c
  \end{array} } \right]
$

which gives

$Y = X A$

I might be missing a transpose. Here you know $Y$ and you know $X$. Inverting we get

$X^{-1} Y = X^{-1} X A = I A$.

Thus
$A = X^{-1} Y $

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
y = ax^2 + bx + c
\implies 
a = -\frac{b x + c - y}{x^2}
\implies
b = -\frac{a x^2 + c - y}{x}
\end{equation}
Given coordinates $ \qquad(1,1)(2,4)(3,9)$

\begin{equation}
(1,1)\implies a = -\frac{1b + c - 1}{1}\implies b = -\frac{1a + c - 1}{1}\\
(2,4)\implies a = -\frac{2b + c - 4}{4}\implies b = -\frac{4a + c - 4}{2}\\
(3,9)\implies a = -\frac{3b + c - 9}{9}\implies b = -\frac{9a + c - 9}{3}
\end{equation}

We do not have a complete solution but $a$ and $b$ appear to be complimentary and $c$ has always been a guess in many math operations. If we eliminate $c$, we can always add it back into the original equation form.

\begin{equation}
(1,1)\implies a = \frac{1 - b}{1}\implies b = 1(1 - a)\\
(2,4)\implies a = \frac{2 - b}{2}\implies b = 2(1 - a)\\
(3,9)\implies a = \frac{3 - b}{3}\implies b = 3(1 - a)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\implies a=\frac{x-b}{x}\qquad b=x(1-a)\\
\implies(a,b)\in\{(x,0).(x,-x)\}\quad\text{for}\quad y=x(ax+b)
\end{equation}